# How can we make query statement to get all rows with either of two values for a column through content Provider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am trying to get all rows with either of two values for a column through content provider, but being novice on content provider I can't yet figure out how to do this.
My query code looks like

```
 case META_INFO:
            retCursor = db.query(
                    TigerContract.MetaInfoEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder
            );
```

And from dbHelper It looks like:

```
    Cursor cursor = myCR.query(TigerContract.MetaInfoEntry.CONTENT_URI, null, TigerContract.MetaInfoEntry.COLUMN_RECORD_STATUS + " =?", new String[]{String.valueOf("Incomplete OR Pending")}, null);
```

I don't know how to do it, basically I want all rows with either Incomplete or Pending values in COLUMN_RECORD_STATUS fields. Please I am waiting for the savior out there with the hammer made of Content Provider stuff.

Comment: Oh come on, obviously selection: `a=? OR a=?` and selectionArgs: `new String[] {a, b}`

Comment: @Selvin is it just that, I thought its not good to ask for same values with two arguments. My bad I was thingking there will be something like OR thing.

Comment: @Selvin And can you help me with the Join for multiple tables using Content Provider. I am confused on that part too.

Comment: No, I'm not your private teacher and you didn't paid me...

Comment: @Selvin thanks for your assist up there and I wish I had such a talent to teach me.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument Projection defines the columns you want to retrieve as a result.
If you provide it as NULL, It will return all the columns.

Your second argument should be array of column names you want in result.

e.g.

**new String[]{"COLUMN_NAME","ANOTHER_COLUMN_NAME"}**

Also your selection should be:

**new String[]{"Incomplete","Pending"}** if you have one of these entries as a value.

Comment: the comment from Selvin at first place worked for me. I didn't knew that I should also use a=? or a = ? in selection string as third parameter.